# Ways to create customer in Magento 2. Random customer registering on Website

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p2

On our Magento 2 website, we have noticed that there are customer accounts with first names and last names consisting of random alphanumeric characters and are registering on almost daily basis.

The common thing about these accounts is that the `Last logged In` time is set to (Never login).

so far we have disabled/restricted REST API for customer registration. we also have added google Recaptcha to our registration form and we also have checked the admin activity log and non of the admins have created any customer.

But still, these customers keep registering.

Can someone suggest (if) there are any other ways to create a customer?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If the registrations are being made from the front end customer registration form, then enabling Magento's native captcha or Google reCaptcha should do the trick.

But as you have already mentioned that Google reCaptcha is enabled and admin activity logs are also enabled, if still, the new registrations are happening, then I suspect, some custom code has been kept on your server, which is creating the customers. It can be in the form of:

- Custom PHP file kept in the document root or pub folder
- Any controller file which someone can hit from the public website
- Any custom event observer which is running on some event to create customers programmatically
- Any cron job which is running on a particular interval and creating customers programmatically

If you know approx. date from when the problem of automatic customers creation started, then you can find the list of files modified after a certain date by using this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985989/is-there-any-way-to-find-out-changed-file-after-some-date-in-whole-project-code

Comment: We have checked all the mentioned points and there is no malicious code or script on our server and also no cron jobs. the frequency of customer creation is now decreased since we add restrictions on REST API to just one or two customers per day, there is also another way of creating customers is by using GraphQL.
What we want now is: Is there any way to get the IP of the customer so that we can create a log whenever a customer gets created through GraphQL? Thank You.

Comment: you can write an observer or plugin before or after the customer is being created.